# Suppress ML.NET console output

Tags: tensorflow, ml.net

I'm using ML.NET in my Console application and loading a tensorflow model with:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(...);
```

But on the model load a bunch of tensor flow debug info is printed on the console, which totally ruins the output of the app. Example:

```
2021-06-19 13:33:14.169642: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: ...
2021-06-19 13:33:14.170923: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-06-19 13:33:14.171820: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-06-19 13:33:14.183684: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:182] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2021-06-19 13:33:14.222754: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:132] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle.
2021-06-19 13:33:14.228002: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:285] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 58349 microseconds.
```

Can't find a way to disable this. Already tried `Console.SetOut(StreamWriter.Null)`, but didn't work.

Comment: What about `Console.SetError`?

Comment: Also doesn’t work

Comment: Try reading [ask] and [mcve] and see if they help. Usually good questions get answers in minutes.

Comment: I think that comes Tensorflow itself so I'm not sure if that can be suppressed - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5dcfc51118817f27fad5246812d83e5dccdc5f72/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc#L90